# Searching a mysql query from python

Tags: python, mysql

I have my Python program linked with MYSQL database and in that database I have a table called 'user_data' where simply different user data are stored. I am trying to select a particular data from the database and display it or use it for some other purpose. The following code works likes a charm:

```
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = 'Anup'")
    rows = self.cursor.fetchone()
    print(rows)
```

However, this program isn't actually feasible for searching in the database. So when i try to modify my program to the one that is feasible, no output is available. Or simply the output is displayed as none. Following is the code that is displaying the error:

```
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    name="Anup"
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = '%s'",('name'))
    rows = self.cursor.fetchone()
    print(rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a parameterised query like this:

```
name="Anup"
self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = %s", (name,))
```

Note here that you do not add single quotes to your query (the DBAPI driver will add that for you), and that a *tuple* (or other sequence such as a list) is passed as an argument to `cursor.execute()`.

An alternative is to use named parameters with values passed as a dictionary:

```
name="Anup"
self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = %(name)s", {'name': name})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong with your code 
***Try This One***

```
self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
name="Anup"
self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = '%s'" % (name))
rows = self.cursor.fetchone()
print(rows)
```

Comment: While this will work, it is not a good idea to use string interpolation to generate queries. Using parameterised queries instead avoids common SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @user5177957 : as per my comment, you should not do it this way due to the possibility of SQL injection. There is some information about this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) (it's for SQLite but it's the same rationale for other drivers such as MySQL)

Comment: to avoid SQL Injection you can use this line 

`self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = %s",('name',))`

Comment: @SaurabhPandey: yes, except that that would pass the literal string `'name'`. The variable `name` should be used, i.e. `(name, )`, not the string `'name'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tuple (note the comma after `name`):

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = %s",('name',))
```